# Show that $\phi(B_n(1)) = B_n(r)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a set

$$B_n(r) = \lbrace x = (x_1,...x_n)\in \mathbb R^n: \sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}<r\rbrace  $$
and I want to show that it is equal to the following set
$$\phi(B_n(1)) = \lbrace \phi(x)\in \mathbb R^n: x\in B_n(1)\rbrace$$
where $\phi$ is defined as the following matrix
$$
\phi = 
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
r x_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & r x_i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r x_n \end{array}\right]_{n\times n}
$$

I start by saying that $\phi$ just moves the point $x$ by some $r\in \mathbb R$ where $r > 0$. So for $r x \in \mathbb R^n$ we have 
$$\sqrt{r^2x_1^2+...+r^2x_n^2}<1 \Rightarrow r\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}<1 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}<\frac{1}{r}$$, but this shows that $\phi(B_n(1)) = B_n(1/r)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Pretty sure the "formula" you gave for $\phi$ is incorrect.

Comment: For general $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ phi is defined as $\phi(E) = \lbrace \phi(x)\in \mathbb R^n: x\in E\rbrace$

Comment: @rioneye I believe he means the matrix. You seem to be implying that $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ but the formula you gave for $\phi$ seems to result in a matrix not an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in B_n(1)$, $\phi(x) = rx$. Note that $|\phi(x)| = |rx| = |r||x| < |r| = r$ so $\phi(x) \in B_n(r)$. Therefore, $\phi(B_n(1)) \subseteq B_n(r)$.

Conversely, if $y \in B_n(r)$, let $x = \frac{1}{r}y$. As $|x| = |\frac{1}{r}||y| < |\frac{1}{r}||r| = 1$, $x \in B_n(1)$. Furthermore, $\phi(x) = rx = y$, so $y \in \phi(B_n(1))$. Therefore, $B_n(r) \subseteq \phi(B_n(1))$.

The two subset relations imply that $\phi(B_n(1)) = B_n(r)$.